# Multiplayer drag and drop Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, multiplayer

I've been working on a real-time multiplayer drag-and-drop using Unity. It has 3 displays.

In Display 1 and 2 (monitor 1 & 2), the user plays and customizes the GameObject and clicks submit button to show the customized GameObject in Display 3 (TV Screen).
And the setup is 1 TV screen (Display 2), 2 monitors (Display 1), and 2 CPUs. Kindly refer to these images.
[image: Refer1]
[image: Refer2]

I used Netcode, and Photon to link the customized GameObject from Display 1 and 2 (Monitor 1 & 2) to share the outcome at TV Screen. The GameObject I set as Prefab and a network object. It was connected but the GameObject did not come out as expected. Are there any options that I'm missing?

Thank You.